# Azure Cloud Shell : Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-cli

I am trying to access a VM created with the ssh file and when i tried to execute the command , i am getting the following error,

```
ssh azureuser@publicIpAddress
```

I get this error

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

and i am not able to connect to VM. any idea where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue in the past, Please try with the below command which explicitly specifies which key to use.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa azureuser@yourpublicip
```

where .ssh/id is the key that you generated

Answer (score 0):

generate new public key

```
ssh-keygen
```

display key to add to azure

```
ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -L'
```

then in azure add the new key
Virtual machines > Reset password > Reset SSH public key

done.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:iCBS3ygINtWJPahAYh3QZDh8Y6joyrlgA6bjBGXerW8 username@LAPTOP-MNE6JNE7
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|=*X=* .          |
|*BoX B           |
|B X + o          |
|+* + o .         |
|+.. o o S        |
|=.   .           |
|*+. .            |
|*+.  .E          |
| o.  ..          |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

above you can observe key is written to file "id_rsa"

You can cat this file and check for key and got azure website vm page

paste this key in reset password section--> Reset SSH Public key -> under support and troubleshoot section

you can paste the above key in the "public ssh key"
[image]